# Conditionally merging dataframes on time variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge, conditional-statements

I have to dataframe that I want to merge on the date, id and time variable in order to compute a duration.

```
from numpy import *
from pandas import *

df1 = DataFrame({
'id': ['a']*4,
'date': ['02-02-2015']*4,
'time_1': ['08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:30:00', '12:45']})

df1
   id   date         time
0   a   02-02-2015  08:00:00
1   a   02-02-2015  09:00:00
2   a   02-02-2015  10:30:00
3   a   02-02-2015  12:45:00

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

df2 = DataFrame({
'id': ['a']*7,
'date': ['02-02-2015']*7,
'time_2': ['08:00:00', '08:09:00', '08:04:01','08:52:36', '09:34:25', '10:30:00', '11:23:38']})

df2
    id  date         time
0   a   02-02-2015  08:00:00
1   a   02-02-2015  08:09:00
2   a   02-02-2015  08:04:01
3   a   02-02-2015  08:52:36
4   a   02-02-2015  09:00:00
5   a   02-02-2015  10:30:00
6   a   02-02-2015  11:23:38
```

The rule that I want my merge to follow is that each row needs in df2 needs to go with the closest previous time in df1.

The intermediate result would be

```
intermediateResult = DataFrame({
'id': ['a']*8,
'date': ['02-02-2015']*8,
'time_1': ['08:00:00', '08:00:00', '08:00:00','08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:30:00', '10:30:00', '12:45'],
'time_2': ['08:00:00', '08:09:00', '08:04:01','08:52:36', '09:34:25', '10:30:00', '11:23:38', nan] })

intermediateResult
    id  date        time_1      time_2
0   a   02-02-2015  08:00:00    08:00:00
1   a   02-02-2015  08:00:00    08:09:00
2   a   02-02-2015  08:00:00    08:04:01
3   a   02-02-2015  08:00:00    08:52:36   # end
4   a   02-02-2015  09:00:00    09:34:25   # end
5   a   02-02-2015  10:30:00    10:30:00
6   a   02-02-2015  10:30:00    11:23:38   # end
7   a   02-02-2015  12:45           NaN
```

Finally, I want to get the time difference between the latest time_2 of each period (inicated with the comment # end) and their corresponding time_1.

The final result would look like this

```
finalResult = DataFrame({
'id': ['a']*4,
'date': ['02-02-2015']*4,
'Duration': ['00:52:36', '00:34:25', '00:53:38', nan]})

finalResult 
    id  date        Duration
0   a   02-02-2015  00:52:36
1   a   02-02-2015  00:34:25
2   a   02-02-2015  00:53:38
3   a   02-02-2015  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different merge methods, came to the same answer. Eventually used `merge_as0f` `direction =backward` as per your request. Unfortunately not similar to yours in the sense that I have no NaN. Happy to help furtherif you gave information on how you end up with NaN in one row.

```
    #Join dateto time and coerce to datetime
    df1['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df1.date.str.cat(df1.time_1,sep=' '))
    df2['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df2.date.str.cat(df2.time_2,sep=' '))
    df2['time_2'] = df2['time_2'].apply(lambda x: (x[-5:]))#StripHours from time_2. I anticipate to use it as duration
    #sort to allow merge_asof
    df1=df1.sort_values('datetime')
    df2=df2.sort_values('datetime')
    #Merge to the dataframes joining using datetime to the nearest hour
    df3=pd.merge_asof(df2, df1,on='datetime', by='id', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2H'),allow_exact_matches=True,direction='backward').dropna()
    #df3=df2.merge(df1, left_on=df2.datetime.dt.hour, right_on=df1.datetime.dt.hour, how='left').drop(columns=['key_0', 'id_y', 'date_y']).fillna(0)#Alternative merge
    df3.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)#set datetime as index
    df3['minutes']=df3.index.minute#Extract minute in each row. Looks to me you want the highest minute in each hour
    #Groupby hour idxmax Helps boolean select the index with the highest minutes in an hour. aND DROP UNWANTED ROWS
    finalResult=df3.loc[df3.groupby([df3.index.hour, df3.date_x])['minutes'].idxmax()].reset_index().drop(columns=['datetime','time_1','date_y','minutes'])
   finalResult.columns=['id','date','Duration(min)']
```

finalResult

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, it solved my problem. The thing with the NaN is that, since there is no value in df2 matching `'12:45:00'` I thought it would return a NaN.

Comment: Also, where did you get the 30:00 from in the Duration(min) columns? I wasn't expecting this. I've noticed that I made a mistake in my post, the `duration` of the index 2 in the final result should be `00:53:38`. I've corrected it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution suggested by @wwnde, I've found one that scales better to my real data set:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = DataFrame({
    'id': ['a']*4,
    'date': ['02-02-2015']*4,
    'time_1': ['08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:30:00', '12:45:00']
})

df2 = DataFrame({
    'id': ['a']*7,
    'date': ['02-02-2015',
        '02-02-2015',
        '03-02-2015', # small change here relatively to the df un my first post
        '02-02-2015',
        '02-02-2015',
        '02-02-2015',
        '02-02-2015'],
    'time_2': ['08:00:00', '08:09:00', '08:04:01','08:52:36', '09:34:25', '10:30:00', '11:23:38']
})


----------------------------------------------------

def preproDf(df1, df2, time_1, time_2, _id, date):
    '''
    Preprocess the dataframes for the following operations

    df1: pd.DataFrame, left dataframe
    df2: pd.DataFrame, right dataframe
    time_1:str, name of the left dataframe
    time_2:str, name of the right dataframe
    _id:str, name of the id variable. Should be the same for both dataframes
    date:str, name of the date variable. Should be the same for both dataframes

    return: None
    '''
    df2[time_2] = df2[time_2].apply(pd.to_datetime)
    df1[time_1] = df1[time_1].apply(pd.to_datetime)

    #sort to allow merge_asof
    df1=df1.sort_values([_id, date, time_1])
    df2=df2.sort_values([_id, date, time_2])



def processDF(df1, df2, time_1, time_2, _id, date):
    # initialisation
    groupKeys = list(df2.groupby([_id, date]).groups.keys())
    dfGroup=groupKeys[0]
    group = df2.groupby([_id, date]).get_group(dfGroup)
    rslt = pd.merge_asof(group, df1, left_on=time_2,  right_on=time_1, by=[_id, date], tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2H'),allow_exact_matches=True,direction='backward')#.dropna()

    # For loop to get the values in an array
    for group in groupKeys[1:]: # Iteration start at the second elmt
        group = df2.groupby([_id, date]).get_group(group)
        item = pd.merge_asof(group, df1, left_on=time_2,  right_on=time_1, by=[_id, date], tolerance=pd.Timedelta('2H'),allow_exact_matches=True,direction='backward')#.dropna()
        rslt = np.vstack((rslt, item))
    rslt = DataFrame(rslt, columns=item.columns)

    # Creating timeDifference variable
    rslt['timeDifference'] = rslt[time_2] - rslt[time_1]

    # Getting the actual result
    rslt = rslt.groupby([_id, date, time_1]).timeDifference.max()
    rslt = pd.DataFrame(rslt).reset_index()
    rslt.rename({time_1: 'openTime'}, axis='columns')

    return rslt
```

The result:

```
preproDf(df1, df2, 'time_1', 'time_2', 'id', 'date')

processDF(df1, df2, 'time_1', 'time_2', 'id', 'date')
    id  date    time_1  screenOnDuration
0   a   02-02-2015  2020-05-29 08:00:00 00:52:36
1   a   02-02-2015  2020-05-29 09:00:00 00:34:25
2   a   02-02-2015  2020-05-29 10:30:00 00:53:38
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to still your answer. I accepted mine because it is the one I used for my problem. I unmarked it and marked yours instead.